# What is the function of the comma between the two names in the newspaper headline below?

Tags: punctuation

I am really confused about the use of the comma between the two names starting  the newspaper headline below. And,  is there any kind of ellipsis ?  " **Obama,  Clinton** Scored Back to Back Home Runs With Their Speeches"

Comment: If you don't put a comma between the two family names, it will become one person's name, "Obama Clinton" and "their" can't work, let alone back-to-back home runs. .

Comment: My first guess was to replace the comma with "and", but I was not quite sure. Now I think it can work well. I would like to give special thanks to Deadrat and Rathony for their reference and comment.

Comment: Yes, "and" could be used, but "saving space" matters in a headline. :-)